# Is it possible to pass arguments to mr job

Tags: python, parallel-processing, mrjob

Given the basic example from the mrJob site for a word count program:

```
from mrjob.job import MRJob


class MRWordFrequencyCount(MRJob):

    def mapper(self, _, line):
        yield "chars", len(line)
        yield "words", len(line.split())
        yield "lines", 1

    def reducer(self, key, values):
        yield key, sum(values)


if __name__ == '__main__':
    MRWordFrequencyCount.run()
```

From command line, this example can be run as `python mrJobFilename.py mrJobFilename.py`. This should run the program on itself and count the words in the file.

So given this example, what if I want to pass in an argument, say `minCount = 3`. With this argument, the reducer would only return words with counts more than `minCount`.

```
from mrjob.job import MRJob


class MRWordFrequencyCount(MRJob):

    def mapper(self, _, line):
        yield "chars", len(line)
        yield "words", len(line.split())
        yield "lines", 1

    def reducer(self, key, values):
        X = sum(values)
        if X > minCount:
            yield key, sum(values)


if __name__ == '__main__':
    MRWordFrequencyCount.run()
```

I tried passing minWord as an argument : `python mrJobFilename.py mrJobFilename.py 3`, but I get an error `OSError: Input path 3 does not exist!`

I also tried setting a variable with sysArg:

```
if __name__ == '__main__':
    minWord = sys.argv[1]
    MRWordFrequencyCount.run()
```

When run with `python mrJobFilename.py mrJobFilename.py < 3` I get an error `bash: 3: No such file or directory`. If I don't use the `<` I get the previous input file not found error.

Finally, I tried inputting a second csv file. The csv file is 2 lines and looks like this:

```
minWord
3
```

It is meant to pass a parameter to mrJobs since it keeps giving me error that second arugment is not an input file. I use mapper_raw to try and load it, but I get a weird error: `UnicodeDecodeError: 'utf-8' codec can't decode byte 0x8f in position 22: invalid start byte`

```
from mrjob.job import MRJob


class MRWordFrequencyCount(MRJob):

    def mapper_raw(self, input_arg1, input_arg2):
        import csv
        f = open(input_path2)
        reader = csv.reader(f)
        next(reader) # skip header
        yield(next(reader))

    def steps(self):
          return [
              MRStep(mapper_raw=self.mapper_raw)
          ]


if __name__ == '__main__':
    MRWordFrequencyCount.run()
```

How can I pass an argument to mrJob? Ultimately I need to do this to pass parameters for differential equation systems which I want to solve in parallel.

Answer (score 0):

You can follow the `mrjob` [document](https://mrjob.readthedocs.io/en/latest/guides/writing-mrjobs.html?#passthrough-options) to add command-line argument like `argparse`.

So your code should look something like this:

```py
from mrjob.job import MRJob

class MRWordFrequencyCount(MRJob):

    def configure_args(self):
        super(MRWordFrequencyCount, self).configure_args()
        self.add_passthru_arg("-m", "--minCount", help="your argument description")

    def mapper(self, _, line):
        yield "chars", len(line)
        yield "words", len(line.split())
        yield "lines", 1

    def reducer(self, key, values):
        X = sum(values)
        if X > self.options.minCount:
            yield key, sum(values)


if __name__ == '__main__':
    MRWordFrequencyCount.run()
```

Use your argument with `self.options.minCount`.

Run command:

```sh
python code.py input.txt --minCount 4
```